Dependency resolution failed error in KDE Discover when trying to install deb
I was trying to install a deb file with KDE Discover on Linux Mint 22 and I keep getting the following error:
Dependency resolution failed
I tried to install it using dpkg but I got this error: 
It might be a problem with the file itself but I'm not sure.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
